# Jekyll serve not working- Cannot find _fluidbox.scss?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, jekyll, bower

```
Configuration file: C:/Users/Simon/Documents/other/Jekyll-project/_config.yml
Configuration file: C:/Users/Simon/Documents/other/Jekyll-project/_config.yml
            Source: C:/Users/Simon/Documents/other/Jekyll-project
       Destination: C:/Users/Simon/Documents/other/Jekyll-project/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating...
Error in _assets/stylesheets/light.scss:50 File to import not found or unreadab
e: ../bower/fluidbox/src/css/_fluidbox.scss.
Load paths:
  C:/Users/Simon/Documents/other/Jekyll-project/_assets/css
  C:/Users/Simon/Documents/other/Jekyll-project/_assets/stylesheets
  C:/Users/Simon/Documents/other/Jekyll-project/_assets/images
  C:/Users/Simon/Documents/other/Jekyll-project/_assets/img
  C:/Users/Simon/Documents/other/Jekyll-project/_assets/fonts
  C:/Users/Simon/Documents/other/Jekyll-project/_assets/javascripts
  C:/Users/Simon/Documents/other/Jekyll-project/_assets/js
  C:/Users/Simon/Documents/other/Jekyll-project/_assets/bower
  C:/Users/Simon/Documents/other/Jekyll-project/_vendor
  Liquid Exception: File to import not found or unreadable: ../bower/fluidbox/s
c/css/_fluidbox.scss. Load paths: C:/Users/Simon/Documents/other/Jekyll-project
_assets/css C:/Users/Simon/Documents/other/Jekyll-project/_assets/stylesheets C
/Users/Simon/Documents/other/Jekyll-project/_assets/images C:/Users/Simon/Docum
nts/other/Jekyll-project/_assets/img C:/Users/Simon/Documents/other/Jekyll-proj
ct/_assets/fonts C:/Users/Simon/Documents/other/Jekyll-project/_assets/javascri
ts C:/Users/Simon/Documents/other/Jekyll-project/_assets/js C:/Users/Simon/Docu
ents/other/Jekyll-project/_assets/bower C:/Users/Simon/Documents/other/Jekyll-p
oject/_vendor in /_layouts/post.html
jekyll 3.3.1 | Error:  File to import not found or unreadable: ../bower/fluidbo
/src/css/_fluidbox.scss.
Load paths:
  C:/Users/Simon/Documents/other/Jekyll-project/_assets/css
  C:/Users/Simon/Documents/other/Jekyll-project/_assets/stylesheets
  C:/Users/Simon/Documents/other/Jekyll-project/_assets/images
  C:/Users/Simon/Documents/other/Jekyll-project/_assets/img
  C:/Users/Simon/Documents/other/Jekyll-project/_assets/fonts
  C:/Users/Simon/Documents/other/Jekyll-project/_assets/javascripts
  C:/Users/Simon/Documents/other/Jekyll-project/_assets/js
  C:/Users/Simon/Documents/other/Jekyll-project/_assets/bower
  C:/Users/Simon/Documents/other/Jekyll-project/_vendor
```

I have no idea what this means. All I did was download a jekyll theme here: http://chalk.nielsenramon.com,

change a few things in _config.yml (Just the twitter/github and profile usernames) and run jekyll serve command in my cmd. This is the error message that shows up. I haven't done jekyll very long, so I apologize

Comment: Your error shows that you are trying to access a css at `_assets/stylesheets/light.scss:50` file named `../bower/fluidbox/sc/css/_fluidbox.scss` that is not found. Would you please share which theme you are using? I think you skipped any theme configuration step.

Answer (score 0):

[From chalk documentation](https://github.com/nielsenramon/chalk#installation), you have to run `bin/setup` before `bundle exec jekyll serve`.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issues outlined above. I realized that you cannot append this to an existing Jekyll build, but instead need to start a new Jekyll project from scratch. This is due to the change bin/setup makes to the environment. If you start a new project, you should have no issue.